# how to make multiple ajax query work on all browsers with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, safari

am working on a project and i found a little problem with my ajax request which am finding hard to fix.
i want to perform multiple ajax requests, in that i mean: i need to perform an ajax request, and if its successful, i will perform another ajax request within the success handler.

here is a sample of my code:

```
var result;
$.post('make_payment.php',{password:pass,amount:50},function(data){
result=data;
if(result=='success'){
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        dataType:"json",
        url:"save_info.php",
        success: function(data){
            if(data.result=='success'){
                alert('success');   
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
}
})
```

This works pretty good on mozilla firefox and google chrome, but does not work on internet explorer and apple safari.
pls i need an assistance on how to make it work on all browser.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Please elaborate. Do both requests get sent? do both requests return with a non-zero status code? what are those status codes?

Comment: Not working in IE and Safari? Can you tell what exactly is happening?

Comment: it does not give any error definition it just return the error handler. unlike in firefox and chrome

Comment: Too little Information to give an answer but my first thought was encoding problem. Both, Safari and IE are very strict when it comes to encoding. Is the data sent by the ajax request encoded in the same way like the comparing data??

Answer (score 0):

Trying using dataType:"jsonp" instead of dataType:"json" . I'm not sure of the reason but long back i had the same issue and that got fixed with this change